# Pull push-notification on iPad to open app in Split View

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ipados, unnotificationserviceextension

When I receive push-notifications on iPad for some apps I can pull them to the side to open app in Split View, but it is not supported by every app.

What should I do with my iOS app to have such behavior?